# What is the Zion Foundation?

Tags: the-matrix, the-animatrix

In *The Matrix Reloaded*, during the scene where the *Nebuchadnezzar* is returning home, there are several seconds of footage of all the impressive machinery which operates the main gate. There is one shot of a set of huge cogs, and on the side of one of them is printed ZION FOUNDATION. Seen below.

[image: Screencap from the movie.]

With the idea that all of the Matrix Universe is canon (since *The Animatrix*, the video games and comics were all produced/directed/written/edited by the Wachowskis) has anyone seen anything that would explain what (or who) the Zion Foundation is? I have not, and the only game I haven't played is the MMO; I've read all the comics. Is there more supplemental material?

Comment: Nicely spot! Considering you have been into all these material, do you possess the extra materials from the old website of the franchise? (The one where you could unlock extra materials like 360 shots with gathering enter codes from various, often hard-to-spot, sources.)

Comment: @naxa: The only stuff I have from the site is the webcomics, and that's only because they've been re-released in a two-volume omnibus.

Comment: Not that this contributes to finding an answer, but it's been addressed [else-site](http://forums.thelastfreecity.com/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=23462) years ago.  Here's to hoping we find the answer over here.

Comment: ...what is the maximum length that is allowed here for an answer? :)

Answer (score 4):

This detail set photo shows that it's not Zion Foundation, but rather Zion ***Foundry***. Presumably the city has its own ironworks to create large metal objects such as these.

[image]

It's possibly that the Zion Streetlight Company is a division of the Zion Foundry (or vice versa)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Discussion at [the site linked to](http://forums.thelastfreecity.com/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=23462) in Solemnity's comment above settles on it actually saying 'ZION FOUNDRY' not 'ZION FOUNDATION'. If you look just past the 'D', you can see a vertical stroke from the left edge of the next letter, which is more consistent with an 'R' than an 'A'.

It would also be a better answer, in the Occam's Razor sense: the mundane explanation that these large pieces of metal were created in a place whose very name means a place that makes large pieces of metal, rather than a cryptic reference to an otherwise-unknown organization.

Comment: Dead link on the site